# How to create a PHP-Unit test for a file download?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

after long thinking about this topic without a result, I hope someone can give me a hint about phpUnit-Test for downloads.  How can I create a phpUnit test for this function, which execute a download for a zip-File? Or is there an oter usual practice  to test a logic like this?

```
   public function createOutput($zipFolderName) {
        $zipFolderName = $zipFolderName."/imageResizer.zip";
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipFolderName);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFolderName));
        readfile($zipFolderName);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like there are a couple components to this function, and each part should be tested to make sure that it is being accomplished correctly:

- builds the correct `$zipFolderName` path
- sets the correct headers
- calculates the correct filesize
- reads the file

It looks like some sort of file handler abstraction could help you easily unit test this method.

```
class FileUtils {
   public getDownloadFileName($folderName) {}
   public getFileSize($file) {}
   public readFile($file) {}
}
```

Now you could inject a file utility instance into your function.  For your production code this class would delgate file operations to actual filesystem, BUT your test would provide a stub/mock allow you to make assertions that your unit is performing the actions expected.

```
 public function createOutput($fileUtilsInstance, $zipFolderName) {
        $zipFolderName = $fileUtilsInstance->getDownloadFileName($zipFolderName);
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipFolderName);
        header('Content-Length: ' . $fileUtilsInstance->getFilesize($zipFolderName));
        $fileUtilsInstance->readFile($zipFolderName);
    }
```

The same tactic could be applied to the `header` method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) library:

> vfsStream is a PHP stream wrapper for a virtual file system that may
>   be helpful in unit tests to mock the real file system. It can be used
>   with any unit test framework, like PHPUnit or SimpleTest.

Same useful info in:

- [PHPUNIT DOC - Mocking the Filesystem section](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)
- Really useful code example in this article - [MOCKING THE FILE SYSTEM USING PHPUNIT AND VFSSTREAM](http://tech.vg.no/2011/03/09/mocking-the-file-system-using-phpunit-and-vfsstream/)

Hope this help. Let me know if you need some examples

Comment: But this has [known issues](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream/wiki/Known-Issues) with handling zip files.